# Using .Split to Split a string and return first integer values (Without LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq

I am able to use Linq to do this but I am struggling to do it without, would prefer without if possible:

Code with LINQ:

```
        string result = sentencewithint
                .Split("")
                .FirstOrDefault(item => Regex.IsMatch(item, @"^\-?[0-9]+$"));

        int firstint = int.Parse(result);

        return firstint;
```

Comment: And what's the reason for preventing LINQ? BTW `result` could be null, you're not checking for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `regex`

```
string sentencewithint = "1567438absdg345";
string result = Regex.Match(sentencewithint, @"^\d+").ToString();
Console.WriteLine(result); //1567438
```

Or using the `TakeWhile` extension methods to get characters from the string in the condition only if they are digits

```
string sentencewithint = "1567438absdg345";
string num = new String(sentencewithint.TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());  
Console.WriteLine(result); //1567438
```

Comment: Don't forget the minus symbol for negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a *simple loop* instead of *Linq*:

```
foreach (string item in sentencewithint.Split(""))
  if (Regex.IsMatch(item, @"^\-?[0-9]+$"))
    return int.Parse(item);

//TODO: Put some default value here (in case no item has been matched)
return -1;
```

Answer (score -1):

`.Split` is not a Linq method. The only Linq you are using is `FirstOrDefault`. But to answer your question, all of .Net is open source, so you can look up the source code and copy that.

[Here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/First.cs) is the source code for `FirstOrDefault`. You could write your own `FirstOrDefaultMethod` like this:

```
    public static TSource? FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) =>
        source.TryGetFirst(out _);
    private static TSource? TryGetFirst<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, out bool found)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.source);
        }

        if (source is IPartition<TSource> partition)
        {
            return partition.TryGetFirst(out found);
        }

        if (source is IList<TSource> list)
        {
            if (list.Count > 0)
            {
                found = true;
                return list[0];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    found = true;
                    return e.Current;
                }
            }
        }

        found = false;
        return default;
    }
```

[Here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs) is the source code for `string`, which includes `Split` on line 975.

Comment: You may not like this answer because I'm not writing the code for you, but referring to the source code will help you with this kind of problem in the future. Give a man a fish...

Comment: "What color do you get when you mix green and red?" "You should go look up electromagnetic spectrum radiation wavelength values." I mean, yes I agree with the "teach a man to fish", but this is more a comment than actually a solution and answer to the problem.

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/174780)

Comment: I've updated my answer to account for your comments

Comment: @gunr2171 While I understand and even agree with your sentiment, your straw man comparison isn't very accurate here. A better comparison would be "What color do you get when you mix green and red?" "You should look at this venn diagram of color combinations that my link points to".